# How do I change button's shape into round without changing button backround image

Tags: android, button

so I'm new into android studio and I am creating an app I want to change all button corners into round but without changing the color of the buttons in drawables because in every button backround I have put an image, I just dont know how to do it

Comment: Use ImageButton instead of Button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ImageButton.

Put this ImageButton to your layout xml.

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/button_drawable" />
```

button_drawable is your button image drawable.

Create button_background.xml drawable into drawable resource.

Drawable > New > Drawable Resource File (example: button_background.xml)
Add this code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners  android:radius="10dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/red"></solid>
</shape>
```

Comment: You just made everything more confusing, I tried this but this doesn't work, see i got like 20 buttons 300to 200 sp height and width in the main page, every button has different image in the backround, and what you said, solved nothing just became more confusing, can I do it with normal button, and not put image button ? anyway thnx for help

Comment: I don't understand what do you want.

Comment: I want the button to have rounded corners and the backround image that I put inside the button also the image to have same borders to fit inside the button, and your advice wasnt helpful

Comment: Background image isn't solid color? If background image is solid color, you should create shape resource xml with corner radius and color. If background image isn't solid color you can create rounded image by dynamically in source code.

Comment: thanks, I figured it out, thanks a lot